# How to declare a variable that can be used in both class1.m and class B.m

Tags: iphone, ios

i have "classmap.m" and annotation.m i have a value of coordinates in "classmap.m" and i need to assign a value in the other class annotation.m.

ex:
class1.m
double start_long;

i want to give pass the value in another one class (annotation.m)

annotation.m

annotation.longitude=Start_long;

how can i do that please give some examples is there.

thanks in advance

Comment: Take variable in the Appdelegate and access it like AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];appd.start_long = // assign some value here

Comment: Better you should use Singleton concept.

Comment: @NishantTyagi No, that is a bad solution.

Answer (score 3):

A better, more efficient, effective and cleaner way is to use Singleton Pattern. A good approach is to keep AppDelegate cleaner and avoid keeping global variables there. Always try to use Singleton classes and objects to keep global variables.

Comment: Instead of creating the new singleton class try to use the existing Singleton class (Appdelegate)

Answer (score 1):

If both classmap.m and annotaion.m are  inherited from NSObject then it's simple annotation:classmap . will give access to the properties of classmap

**ClassMap**

```
@interface classmap : NSObject

@property  double longitude;

@end

#import "classmap.h"

@implementation classmap

@synthesize longitude;


@end
```

**Annoataion**

```
@interface annotation : classmap

@property  double start_long;

@end

#import "annotation.h"

@implementation annotation

@synthesize start_long;


@end
```

Now the assigning can be done easily in annotation.longitude=Start_long the place you need

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, it is the right approach.  I would give code sample that would greatly help OP.  Since this is a very basic question.

Comment: what kind of clarification you need @user523234

Answer (score 0):

Take the variable in the **Appdelegate** and access it anywhere in the project .
Access it like

Assign Value

```
AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appd.start_long = -17.002// assign some value here
```

Read Value

```
AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
double dVal  = appd.start_long ;
```

Comment: The app delegate is not a dumping ground for things you don't know how to share otherwise. Its role is (what it says) to be a delegate for the UIApplication instance.

Comment: Instead of creating the new singleton class try to use the existing Singleton class (Appdelegate)

Answer (score 0):

The `Singleton` pattern is a weapon which should be used sparingly as it makes a concrete dependancy on the `ClassMap` object for everything which uses it.

While using a Singleton will achieve what you want right now which is access to a property in `ClassMap` but you set yourself up for future coding issues.

What happens when you have multiple `ClassMap` instances for example?

Singletons are better suited to things which do universal jobs. Things which are tools.  e.g `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` or `[NSFileManager defaultManager]`

A different solution is to use [Dependancy Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which creates a direct connection between the object `Annotation` which needs the `ClassMap` object.

In brief `ClassMap` declares a property

`@property double start_long;`

you pass the `ClassMap` object to the `Annotation` object when you instantiate.

```
Annotation.h

@interface Annotation:NSObject

-(instancetype)initWithClassMap:(ClassMap *)amap;

@end
```

and…

```
Annotation.m

@interface Annotation() {

    ClassMap *_map;

}

@end

@implementation Annotation

-(instancetype)initWithClassMap:(ClassMap *)amap {

self = [super init];
if(self) {
   _map = amap;
}
return self;

}

-(void)doSomething {

self.longitude = _map.start_long;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use delegation.In your classmap.m declare

```
@protocol classmapDelegate <NSObject>

  -(void)didchangeCoordinateValue:(double)longitude;

@end
```

annotation should confirm to this protocol and when ever the value in classmap is changed, you could get the event tin Annotation class.